# Org Mode: Difference in results when evaluating code block and evaluating called code block

Tags: org-mode

I am a beginner who wants to evaluate a Call to a code block in an org-file and get the same results as when I evaluate the actual code block. Like so:

```
#+NAME: Myblock
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output raw
  (progn
    (princ "Hello"))
#+END_SRC
```

Which gives:

```
#+RESULTS:  
Hello
```

But when I do

```
#+CALL: Myblock()
```

It gives me

```
#+RESULTS:
: Hello
```

I tried to give arguments to the call, but it didn't seem to affect it at all.

Please help!

/HC

Comment: Which version of Org-mode are you using (`M-x org-version`)? I tested your example on `9.0.9` and did *not* see the colon.

Comment: I am using 8.2.10, that I guess came with the Emacs installation. I am on a machine using Mac OS X Sierra. Thank you for answering! I will look into how I can upgrade org!

Comment: I upgraded, but it then says that execution of the code block has been blocked. It doesn't matter whether try to evaluate the code or the call. Also, ox-pandoc stops working properly when I upgrade. I remember now that I had to remove the org library from .emacs/elpa in order to make ox-pandoc work.

Comment: For a moment I had a thought that it might have to do with the side-effect/return value dichotomy in this particular case, but tested it more explicitly and no, that's not the case.

Comment: The worst part is that I need ox-pandoc badly, so even if I can get 9.0.9 to work in this case, I still can't use it on a daily basis until ox-pandoc works with 9.0.9 too.

Comment: What's the problem with the original behavior of `8.2.10`? Isn't the colon just a display/presentation artifact present in Org-mode buffers?

Comment: I tried a longer example with several lines and removed ":results output raw" from the code block. Evaluating the block then gave only the last instruction in the code, as expected. I then put the excluded part in the call instead, like so: "#+CALL: Longerblock[:results output raw]()". Evaluating this call resulted in all the code's instructions, as expected, *but* with a colon first, i.e. just like before. But this means it is the "raw" part that doesn't work for me, it would seem.

Comment: The problem with the colon is that I can't easily use printc to output a line that Org-mode interprets like a table. (I'm sorry if I'm not using the right terminology here -- I am a beginner!)

Comment: I solved it! It's not pretty, but: "#+CALL: Longerblock[:results output]() :results raw" gives the correct result. I wish I could do that in just one word though!

Comment: I see, it's not pretty :). But at least it does the job.

Comment: There has to be a way to make a shorthand for it, like in a preamble or something. Or maybe I initially formatted the output instructions in the code block in a poor way?

Comment: You could try language-specific headers like [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Language_002dspecific-mode-properties.html#Language_002dspecific-mode-properties).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have to look into it -- lots of fun stuff to read and learn!

Comment: Good luck. Org-mode is a universe unto itself :p.

Comment: If someone else gets this problem: Doing what Wojciech Gac suggested with language specific headers works in part. Putting "#+PROPERTY: header-args:emacs-lisp :results output raw" works when you evaluate all emacs-lisp code blocks directly. When you call them, you have to add ":results raw" at the end of the call for things to output without a colon. I can't find a way to set global header-args for "CALL" that differentiates between insider and end header args. But still, it looks reasonably neat in the org file now. Thank you again for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Once upgraded, add () to the #+call: line.  This works for me.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out -- I forgot to add "()" when I wrote the post. I corrected it now. In the org document I've had them all along though. It would seem upgrading solves the issue, only I can't get the upgrade to work properly (see the comments on the initial post). Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Hans, when you upgrade org-mode you should also install org-plus-contrib. I had the same problem when I upgraded to version 9, it didn't execute the source code blocks until I installed that additional package. See http://orgmode.org/elpa.html